# Losing sound after installing wine 1.5 (+python 2.7)?

Tags: linux, audio, python

I have a desktop and a laptop computer. Since I wanted to run IrfanView (that works great now!), I installed wine 1.5.22, which involved installing 1 GB of dependencies. The desktop continues to work fine, on the laptop, I have lost all sound.

I saw some message in Banshee saying that it wants some python libraries for sound or something like that and that it cannon find them.

Can you offer me any suggestions? Thanks in advance! I have Linux Mint 14 32-bit